# Select an element and apply animation to child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to select an element, add hover to it, then have it select the child of that element.  So, in this case, the hover should select the div and apply the animation to the p nested inside of it.

I have looked around on the w3schools website.  I thought adding the :only-child selector might work, but it doesn't seem to.  Perhaps that is not a valid syntax.

If possible, I would like to keep this CSS if possible, but perhaps it needs jquery.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Any input is appreciated.

HTML

```
<section class="secLI">
    <a href="index.html">
      <h3>Home</h3> 
    </a>
    <div id="dropDown1" class="dropHide">
        <p class="dropP">
            This is information about the company.......
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#dropDown1:hover:only-child {
        /*****Display P in Drop Down on Hover*****/
            -webkit-animation-name: displayP;
              -webkit-animation-duration: .12s;
              -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important; 
              -moz-animation-name: displayP;
              -moz-animation-duration: .12s;
              -mozt-animation-delay: 1s;
              -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;    
              -ms-animation-name: displayP;
              -ms-animation-duration: .12s;
              -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
              -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important; 
              -o-animation-name: displayP;
              -o-animation-duration: .12s;
              -o-animation-delay: 1s;
              -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;               
              animation-name: displayP;
              animation-duration: .12s;
              animation-delay: 1s;
              animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    }

              /*****Display P in Drop Down*****/
            @-webkit-keyframes displayP {
                  from { opacity: 0; }
                  to { opacity: 1; }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#dropDown1:hover .dropP {
```

Should do the trick. The .dropP specifies the element with class dropP that is a child of #dropDown1 when #dropDown1 is being hovered.

Comment: I am still not getting this to work.  I worked the code into a codepen.  Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/blue11/pen/syAui)

Answer (score 0):

Hover somewhere below **Home** to see the text showing :)
You need to add prefixes for all vendors in you keyframes for this to work properly .

Change your css like this

```css
.dropP{
  opacity: 0;
}
#dropDown1:hover .dropP {
  
  -webkit-animation-name: displayP;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
  -moz-animation-name: displayP;
  -moz-animation-duration: .12s;
  -mozt-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
  -ms-animation-name: displayP;
  -ms-animation-duration: .12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
  -o-animation-name: displayP;
  -o-animation-duration: .12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 1s;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
  animation-name: displayP;
  animation-duration: .12s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
}
/*****Display P in Drop Down*****/

@-webkit-keyframes displayP {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes displayP {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes displayP {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes displayP {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes displayP {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="secLI">
  <a href="index.html">
    <h3>Home</h3> 
  </a>
  <div id="dropDown1" class="dropHide">
    <p class="dropP">
      This is information about the company.......
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I am still not getting this to work.  I worked the code into a codepen.  Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/blue11/pen/syAui)